# Qt5 How to convert DATA_BLOB to QByteArray

Tags: c++, sqlite, qt5, qbytearray

I'm currently working on a Qt Project which involves integration of the DigitalPersona U.are.U Fingerprint Scanner. The only problem I'm facing right now is the conversion of the Fingerprint DATA_BLOB template to QByteArray so as to store it into SQLite database. How to I go about that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally found a solution to this.

```
QByteArray arr= QByteArray((const char *)dataBlob->pbData, dataBlob->cbData);
```